# How to avoid imageresizing if width and height is same as original?

Tags: imageresizer

Is there a way (param) to avoid Imageresizing to process an image if the height and width are the same as original ?

If not, where and how do I cancel the scale process in a plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The ImageResizer does not *scale* images that are already the appropriate size**. It does, however, decode them, strip metadata, and re-encode them into a web-compatible and web-efficient format (usually jpg or png).

If you're wanting the ImageResizer to serve the original file, skipping the entire process, that's a different question, which I'll try to answer below.

Here's the primary challenge with that goal: To discover the width and height of the source image file, you must decode it - at least partially.

This optimization is only useful (or possible) in limited circumstances

1. The format of the source file allows you to parse the width & height without loading the entire file into memory. JPG/PNG yes, TIFF - no, 30+ formats supported by the FreeImageDecoder, no.
2. The source file is on local, low-latency disk storage, and is IIS accessible - eliminates UNC path and plugins S3Reader, SqlReader, AzureReader, RemoteReader, MongoReader, etc.
3. No URL rewriting rules are in place.
4. No custom plugins are being used.
5. The image is already in a web-optimized format with proper compression settings, with metadata removed.
6. No other URL commands are being used
7. No watermarking rules are in place.
8. You do not need to control cache headers.
9. You are 100% sure the image is not malicious (without re-encoding, you can't ensure the file can't be both a script and a bitmap).

**In addition, unless you cached the result, this 'optimization' wouldn't, in fact, improve response time or server-side performance. Since the dimension data would need to be decoded separately, it would add uniform, significant overhead to all requests whether or not they happened to have a dimension match.**

The only situation in which I see this being useful is if you spend a lot of time optimizing compression in Photoshop and don't want the ImageResizer to touch it unless needed. If you're that concerned, just don't apply the URL in that scenario. Or, set `process=no` to keep the original bytes as-is.

It's definitely possible to make a plugin to do this; but it's not something that many people would want to use, and I can't envision a usage scenario where it would be a net gain.

If you want to plunge ahead, just handle the `Config.Current.Pipeline.PreHandleImage` event and replace `e.ResizeImageToStream` with code that parses the stream returned by `e.GetSourceImage()`, apply your dimension logic (comparing to `Config.Current.GetImageBuilder().GetFinalSize()`, then reset the stream and copy it verbatim if desired like this:

```
 using (Stream source = e.GetSourceImage())
     StreamExtensions.CopyToStream(source,stream); //4KiB buffer
```

That might not handle certain scenarios, like if the image actually needs to be resized 1px smaller, but you're adding 1 px border, etc, but it's close. If you're picky, look at the source code for GetFinalSize and return the image bounds instead of the canvas bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the very analysing answer :) My problem is just that: We dont want to mess up an allready "by hand" optimized image, but I will reconsider and try to find another solution to the problem. And if no other is found I now know how to create my plugin :) ! Thanks again !

Comment: If you don't want to mess up a hand optimized image, just don't add a querystring, and ImageResizer won't touch it. The server can't know whether the image it's dealing with is hand-optimized or not, therefore it can't make the decision you're asking it to.