# Conditionally resize images using imageresizing.net

Tags: imageresizer

I want to intercept the imageresizing.net pipeline to conditionally resize an image. The scenario is this.

Any image 600px or larger should be resized down to 600px wide

if an image is 300-> 599px it should be resized to 300px wide

if its less than 150px it should be padded with whitespace to 300px wide.

I know i can achieve each of the above using the library but i don't know in advance of making the call the size of the source image. Is there an entry point where i can intercept the **original** image size and adjust the resize criteria as above?

I did find this but I'm not certain exactly how to implement it. [How to avoid imageresizing if width and height is same as original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121444/how-to-avoid-imageresizing-if-width-and-height-is-same-as-original)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this in an efficient manner, you would have to store the source file width/height somewhere fast. Opening the source file each time isn't acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have some boilerplate code where I can pick up the source image size from? The implementation of the problem above isn't needed, I'm just struggling with obtaining the values.

Comment: I'm going to revise my approach, the source images in this case are remote so as you say this won't work in a performant manner.