# How to stop Imageresizer increasing picture size

Tags: imageresizer

We have the following code:

```
var destStream = new MemoryStream();
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(pictureBinary, destStream, new ResizeSettings());
var result = destStream.ToArray();
```

"pictureBinary" variable here is an array of content of input picture file. If I got it right, then size of "destStream" should be the same as "result" because no any real resizing is done. But for some reasons Imageresizer increases file size of uploaded pictures.

You can download input and output file using the following links - http://downloads.nopcommerce.com/imageresizer_pictures/input.png and http://downloads.nopcommerce.com/imageresizer_pictures/output.png

**UPDATE:** and the same issue even if I try resize a picture. My original image size is 440x350px. When I try to resize it to 300x238px, then its filesize increases several times. Why? I shouldn't happen

Answer (score 2):

ImageResizer always re-encodes images you provide to it via the Managed API. The URL API, on the other hand, only processes the image if you give it commands.

Images from untrusted data sources should always be re-encoded.

The following questions are very similar to yours and will give you more detail

- [How to avoid imageresizing if width and height is same as original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121444/how-to-avoid-imageresizing-if-width-and-height-is-same-as-original/11122256#11122256)
- [Is there PNG compression in ImageResizer like tinypng.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709937/is-there-png-compression-in-imageresizer-like-tinypng-org)
- [Png compression and image resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829200/png-compression-and-image-resizing)

ImageResizer will provide better Jpeg compression than you can find elsewhere - but PNG compression is a different class of algorithm. Given hours and gigabytes of RAM, you can make *very* small PNG files. If you want to do it fast, you can only use 1/50th as many optimizations.

Comment: OK, let's resize. My original image size is 440x350px. When I try to resize it to 300x238px, then its filesize increases several times. Why?

Comment: Please see the links in the answer; it's essentially the same question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why there is no PNG compression at all. In the other post you talked about 10-20 seconds to perform. When I save an image in Paint.NET it is done immediately and results in a file of ~20KB here. When I get it through Image Resizer and keep the same dimensions the same file becomes ~46KB.